# Can we have labels on top of each bar in stacked graph using angular.flot library in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How to write value of each bar on top of bars. I am using **angular.flot** library for graph, in **angular.js**

**Data passed to flot:**

```
list = [{"bars": "#8CC051","data": [[{0: 1}, {1: null}],[{0: 6}, {1: 216}],[{0: 11}, {1: 224}],[{0: 16}, {1: 256}]]}, {"bars": "#1cb09a","data": [[{0: 1}, {1: null}],[{0: 6}, {1: 196}],[{0: 11}, {1: 204}],[{0: 16}, {1: 246}]]}]
option passed to flot:
{
plotOptions: { column: { stacking: 'normal', dataLabels: { enabled: true, style: { textShadow: '0 0 3px black' } } } }, series: { shadowSize: 0, stack: true }, bars: { show: true, fill: true, lineWidth: 0, barWidth: 3.0, },xaxis: { show: false }, yaxis: { show: false }, grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true, borderWidth: 0, color: '#fff' }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: I my code is in seperate files, and data i am generating data for graph from data which i receive from back-end. I will add the json i provide to angular.flot.

Comment: list = [{"bars": "#8CC051","data": [[{0: 1}, {1: null}],[{0: 6}, {1: 216}],[{0: 11}, {1: 224}],[{0: 16}, {1: 256}]]},
       {"bars": "#1cb09a","data": [[{0: 1}, {1: null}],[{0: 6}, {1: 196}],[{0: 11}, {1: 204}],[{0: 16}, {1: 246}]]}]

Comment: plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: {
          shadowSize: 0,
          stack: true
        },
        bars: {
          show: true,
          fill: true,
          lineWidth: 0,
          barWidth: 3.0,
        },

Comment: xaxis: {
          show: false
        },
        yaxis: {
          show: false
        },
        grid: {
          hoverable: true,
          clickable: true,
          borderWidth: 0,
          color: '#fff'
        },

Comment: You can edit your question and include your code in it.